# Getting solana balance after transaction (transfered amount)

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, account, balance

[image: object of solana transaction]

Hello all, Pretty new to Solana I have a question how can I get the transaction amount, I was told to use the PostBalances and preBalances, but not really sure how to go about it. any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by transaction amount ? fee ? transfer amount ?

Comment: transfer amount

Answer (score 1):

In Solana network values shared are called lamport.
Subtraction will give you lamport value.

```
    const LAMPORT = 0.000000001; // SOL
let transactionInfo = await connection.getTransaction(signature);
        console.log('transactionInfo', JSON.stringify(transactionInfo));
        const transactionMeta = transactionInfo.meta;
let lamportsSent = transactionMeta.postBalances[0] - transactionMeta.preBalances[0];
lamportsSent =  Math.abs(lamportsSent);
        const solanaSent = lamportsSent * LAMPORT;
```

For reference
https://docs.solana.com/integrations/exchange#versioned-transaction-migration